# Java JSpinner odd integer display behavior when using 9s

Tags: java, jspinner

I am trying to set the maximum value of a JSpinner to match the maximum integer value so the number can be used in a SQL query of a MySQL database. Here is the set up code for the spinner and model:

```
SpinnerNumberModel spinnerModel = 
        new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1);
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(spinnerModel);
JFormattedTextField formatSpinner = (
        (JSpinner.NumberEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField();
((NumberFormatter) formatSpinner.getFormatter()).setAllowsInvalid(false);
```

But when testing this by entering 9s it allows the user to enter an additional 9, except once you get to 9,999,999,999 it changes the value to 1,410,065,398 and if you hit 9 again it changes the value to 1,215,752,102 and stops accepting any more digits. From there you can increment the value normally until you get to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, where the formatter correctly stops the spinner.

The spinner works normally by blocking the last digit if any other number is used (i.e., 3s only let the user enter 333,333,333).